# Cucumber won't find page ID - Ruby, Capybara, Selenium

Tags: selenium-webdriver, cucumber, capybara

I'm having difficulty here.  I'm trying to get Cucumber to find this elements ID on page. First to confirm it's present, secondly to click on it.

```
<a id="ga_Vehicle alerts_Vehicle tax: Expired" href="/vehicles/fleetRecords?dol.expired=true&amp;filter=expired" class="alert-3-row" title="Vehicles with expired tax"></a>.
```

It looks like the ID is embedded into the hyperlink.

When I try

```
Then /^I can verify that expired hyperlink is present within the alert$/ do
find_by_id "a_Vehicle alerts_Vehicle tax: Expired"
end
```

The element can't be found.

Where am i going wrong?

Cheers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your ID should not have spaces in it. From here: http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-html40/types.html#h-6.2

> ID and NAME tokens must begin with a letter ([A-Za-z]) and may be followed by any number of letters, digits ([0-9]), hyphens ("-"), underscores ("_"), colons (":"), and periods (".").

Spaces are not valid characters in an ID and will thoroughly confuse any dom parsers, jquery, CSS, selenium, etc. You should remove the spaces from your ID and replace them with underscores if you really need that much info in your ID. If you're using the ID to store metadata about the HTML node, I would advise against that.

What it looks like you might be after is adding things like a_Vehicle and alerts_Vehicle as classes.

Answer (score 1):

Based on your HTML snippet, the value of the `href` attribute is `id="ga_Vehicle alerts_Vehicle tax: Expired"`.  Your locator is slightly different: `"a_Vehicle alerts_Vehicle tax: Expired"`.